# Inner Island Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

Finish the sentence with a specific word.

**I solved this puzzle by using a...**

```
                  IMJONL
                  
                  3S2DRW4 

                  5GU7HT6
                  
                  VJGNH
                 
                  9K08LIP
                  
                  ZWQS
                  
                  3DT5EF4
                 
                  ZESRXFC
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved this puzzle by using a...

> ...**KEYBOARD**!

And not just in the normal way, but also by observing...

> ...that if I highlighted the letters and numbers in each group on a keyboard, these formed a ring around a specific letter (on its own 'inner island', if you like...). Reading these letters off in the order presented spells out the word **KEYBOARD**:
>
>  [image: Letters surrounded by the listed characters]

Full disclosure:

> I must confess... I also used a mouse!